# How to set annotation property/attribute programmatically?

Tags: java, spring, spring-annotations, transactional

So I need to set the timeout parameter for @Transactional annotation. This property will come from a property file which I'm not able to do since I'm encountering "The value for annotation attribute Transactional.timeout must be a constant expression". Something like this

```
@Value("${mytimeout}")
private int myTimeout;

@Transactional(timeout=myTimeout)
public void myMethod(){
}
```

The only time the timeout attribute can be set by a variable is when a variable is final.

So, I was thinking if it is possible to set the timeout property programmatically while using the @Transaction annotation. Or any other way I can set this attribute Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- If you need the same timeout for all transactions, you can configure it as `defaultTimeout` in your transaction manager
- Otherwise, you may try to play with custom `AnnotationTransactionAttributeSource` and `TransactionAnnotationParser`, though you'll need to replace `<tx:annotation-drivern>` with manual definition of corresponding beans in order to configure a custom attribute source.

  Then you can create a custom annotation and make `TransactionAnnotationParser` generate `TransactionDefinition` with custom timeout when it sees your annotation.
- Otherwise, the easiest way to solve this problem is to give up using `@Transactional` and use `TransactionTemplate` instead.